# Disable Payment Method By JS

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, recurring, subscription

I have a requirement to disable the payment method based on a custom product attribute in the cart and payments page, whose value is stored in the cookie local. Till Now I have been able to get a cookie value in the JS, but how can I disable the particular payment like for example "checkmo" OR "purchaseorder" from JS in the cart and the payment page?

Thanks in advance.